# ZF2 Home Url maps to 0.0.0

Tags: zend-framework2

Hi i came here since I have some troubles with my routing. This is what troubles me:

`$this>url('home')` maps the url to 0.0.0, since zf is generating relative paths for most of the time, so I expected it to be something like `/` or the complete namen taken from the `$_SERVER`array

my home config entry:

```
         'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/[/:page][/]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'MyModule\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                    'page' => 1,
                ),
                'constraints' => array(
                        'page'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

this is where I "found out" since my paginator is spitting out urls like `http://0.0.0/2`

anybody knows how to resolve that issue?

Running on my localhost from domain "test.com" I guess it somehow comes from that, but it's still bothersome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed `'route'    => '/[/:page][/]',` to `'route'    => '/[:page][/]',` now it's working like a charm, i should go to bed -_-

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late adding this but i encountered another "bug" from this. As you see there is an optional `page` parameter and an optional trailing `/`, since the route which is basically mysite.com/1/ maps to `//` (default for page is 1) i had to remove the trailing `/`